# Why can't I parse my code using scala parser combinators

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I am trying to parse a simple syntax like so

```
mod A do

end
```

where between the do block will either be content or not. For some odd reason I am not parsing this correctly using this combinator.

```scala
def module: Parser[Any] = "mod" ~> moduleIdent ~ "do" ~ opt(rep(_)) ~ "end"
```

where `_` is the repetition of an optional function definition parser.

I am getting the following error.

```
[2.1] failure: 'do' expected but 'e' found

end
```

---

`moduleIdent` code:

```scala
def moduleIdent: Parser[String] = "[A-Z]+".r ~ opt(ident) ^^ {
    case first ~ optAll => optAll match {
        case Some(all) => first ++ all
        case None => first
    }
}
```

running the parsing code:

```scala
parseAll(module, Source.fromFile(source).mkString)
```

where source is the given code that is failing.

---

Sometimes I am also getting "end of input" error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using the JavaTokenParsers class.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It would be best to post a [mcve], but it looks like `ident` matches `do`, so your `do` keyword is interpreted as the optional identifier, so it's expecting another `do` after it.

Comment: On a side not I would recommend against using Scala parser combinators: it's not actively developed, poorly documented and has less readable syntax than alternatives. No other parser combinators library produces as many questions as this. And personally I would not attribute this to its popularity.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I forgot to answer my own question because I found what the issue was. Firstly @sepp2k you are right but I fixed the problem using a regex. And I am aware it is poorly documented but this is being used for a third year project and this was recommended. It is all working great tho! Cheers!